# Run all csv columns at the same time

Tags: python, csv

I have a big block of code that repeats the same thing for example :

```
                      What I did was create a csv with the following: 
column1, column2, column3
```

I read the csv in a for loop

```
for row in reader:
```

However, the above gets me the value one by one, not all columns at once.

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes, 
Right now. With the above code, I get all the values (temptreevalue, tempwatervalue, tempplantvalue, tempxvalue) and publish them using Json.

What I'm  trying to accomplish is instead of doing everything manually, to have a csv file that can replace the manual function.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you looking for? It will assign column1, column2, column3 values to x, y, and z variables. In python it's called unpacking. Basically, you assign each value in the list (row) to the variables.

```
x, y, z = row
```

Here is an example of a complete code:

```
import csv

with open("some_file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        x, y, z = row
        print(x, y, z)
```

you can do the same if you just need to print output instead of variables:

```
print(*row)
```

Comment: Hey Vlad, Thanks for the help. That gives me all the rows at once, if I do a time.sleep(1) I get one row every second, not all rows in one second.
What I'm trying to do is publish json 

 temptreevalue" : temptreevalue,"tanklevel":tanklevel, "watervalue",watervalue

Comment: Take a look at yield. It will allow you to pull one row at the time. Let me know if that is what you looking for. https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't expect the index or structure of the csv to change, I would create list and enumerate or zip through them.

```
listValues = [x,y,z]
csvCols = ['column1,'column2','column3']

mapped = set(zip(listValues,csvCols))
```

For reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-in-python/